# How to make a command-line tool executable in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix

I just finished writing my very first command-line tool in Objective-C, compiled it, and now I'm curious about how one would go about making it executable as a command.

For example, right now to use the program I have to type in `./filename -args` into Terminal. I'd like to be able to only type in `filename` and execute the program.

I tried using `sudo chmod a+x filename` but no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo cp filename /usr/local/bin/
```

Or add the directory containing `filename` into `$PATH`. Like as all other UNIX-derived OSs.

Comment: @Calvin: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/filename`.

Comment: I did that, but now when I type in "filename" anywhere it says <code>/usr/local/bin/filename: No such file or directory</code>, which leads me to believe it's still stored somewhere?

Comment: @Calvin: since `/usr/local/bin/filename` no longer exists, `rm` can't find it, thus telling you `/usr/local/bin/filename: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I know that -- I removed the file, but when I try to use the command "filename" in any directory, it tells me that there is no such file or directory rather than telling me "filename: command not found"

Comment: If you start a new shell you'll get command not found; the one you're using has cached the existence of the file.

Comment: @Calvin L:If you're going to learn to program then you really also need to spend a little time learning the basics of the operating system that you are using.

Comment: Once it's found a command, bash caches its location for faster look up next time you try to run it.  Apparently, you can clear the cash with `hash -r`